# Foreign key NullReferenceExcepetion in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sqlite, foreign-keys, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am new with Entity Framework so I don't know if I am doing right or this is a bug in new Entity Framework Core. I need to do a class for related pages like 1 page is related to another one. I have class `Page`

```
public class Page 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string UrlName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public List<RelatedPages> RelPages1 { get; set; }
    public List<RelatedPages> RelPages2 { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my class for `RelatedPages`:

```
public class RelatedPages
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? Page1ID { get; set; }
    public Page Page1 { get; set; }
    public int? Page2ID { get; set; }
    public Page Page2 { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get the `Page` instance from `RelatedPages` and conversely, like `context.RelatedPages.Single(r => r.ID==1).Page2.UrlName` though I have NullReferenceException.
This is in my `OnModelCreating` in `DbContext`:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<RelatedPages>()
                    .HasOne(x => x.Page1)
                    .WithMany(x => x.RelPages1)
                    .HasForeignKey(x => x.Page1ID);

 modelBuilder.Entity<RelatedPages>()
                    .HasOne(x => x.Page2)
                    .WithMany(x => x.RelPages2)
                    .HasForeignKey(x => x.Page2ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to include `Page2`.

Change `context.RelatedPages.Single(r => r.ID==1).Page2.UrlName` to `context.RelatedPages.Include(x=>x.Page2).Single(r => r.ID==1).Page2.UrlName`